# Cancellation in C++

Tags: numerical-algorithms, numerical-analysis, c++

I am trying to figure out what the problem with the following expression in C++ is:

```
y=std::log(std::cosh(x));
```

My first intention was that there might occure a Cancellation due to the `cosh(x)` part, because it is definde as $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$ and the computation of $e^x$ with `double x` results in Cancellation.

Am I on the right track?
Or is there something different that causes Cancellation?

Comment: What is the problem? Does the compiler complain or is the resultant valurnorna erong?

Comment: @ghellquist It has something to do with cancellation. Somehow this code can lead to bad results if executet with double values.

Comment: @Pepsilon7 Can you give an example with a particular input value, the expected output, and the actual incorrect output?

Comment: `std::cosh(x)` is not computed as $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$. For example, in the range $0\leq x\leq \ln(2)/2$ it is computed as $1+\frac{(e^x-1)^2}{2e^x}$, where the $e^x-1$ is not computed using `std::exp` and subtracting $1$, but using `std::expm1`. In the range $\ln(2)/2\leq x\leq 22$ is computed as $\frac{e^x+1/e^x}{2}$. From $22\leq x\leq \ln(\operatorname{maxdouble})$ it is computed as $e^x/2$.

Comment: @plop So does that mean, that if $x$ is close to $0$ that there is some cancellation due to the term $\frac{(e^x-1)^2}{2e^x}$ because in this case $e^x$ is close to $1$?

Comment: @Pepsilon7 If the $e^x-1$ were implemented as `std::exp(x)-1` there would be, but that is not what `std::cosh(x)` does. The $e^x-1$ part is computed using `std::expm1(x)`, which doesn't present the catastrophic cancellation of `std::exp(x)-1`.

Comment: @plop So there is in fact no cancellation at all?

Comment: Well, on computing $\cosh(x)$ using `std::cosh(x)` alone, there isn't. Now, the composition $\ln(\cosh(x))$ does present some cases in which it is more convenient to evaluate it in other forms than `std::log(std::cosh(x))`. For example, since `std::cosh(x)`, for small values of $x$ actually does `1+std::expm1(x)*std::expm1(x)/(std::exp(x)+std::exp(x))` and the part that is added to $1$ can be close to $0$, then instead of `std::log` it is better to compute it as `std::logp1(std::expm1(x)*std::expm1(x)/(std::exp(x)+std::exp(x)))` using the function `std::logp1`.

Comment: [Here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-128/e_coshl.c.html) you can see a common implementation of`std::cosh(x)`.

Comment: I haven't looked at other ranges of $x$. It looks like in the range $22\leq x\leq \ln(\operatorname{maxdouble})$ since `std::cosh(x)` is just `std::exp(x)/2`, then maybe you can implement $\log(\cosh(x))$ just as `x-std::log(2)`.

Comment: For $\ln(\operatorname{maxdouble})\leq x$ they either let `\std::cosh(x)` overflow or compute it as `std::exp(x/2)/2*std::exp(x/2)`. I think that in all these cases $\log(\cosh(x))$ is just `x-std::log(2)`. Of course `std::log(2)` can just be precomputed `const double log2 = 0.6931471805599453094172321214581765680755001343602552541206800094`

Comment: @plop Oh I see, this makes sense. Thank you very much indeed for your help!

Comment: @AaronRotenberg The problematic cases are when $\cosh(x)$ is large and when it is close to $1$. For example, $\log(\cosh(123456))$, when computed as `std::log(std::cosh(123456))` overflows, while it is about $123455.3$, which is nowhere near to overflow. Similarly, $\log(\cosh(0.0000000000001234))$, when computed as `std::log(std::cosh(0.0000000000001234))` it gives `0.0`, while it is about $7.61378\times10^-{27}$, which is nowhere near to underflow. Those examples, when computed as in the comments above, give results close to the actual values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me summarize what I wrote in the comments. It is not a complete answer, since the intervals on which to apply each formula still need to be investigated.

It is enough to assume $x\geq0$, since $\cosh(x)$ is even.

The type of cancellation that occurs when evaluating, in finite precision floating point (FP2), the expression

$$\log(\cosh(x))$$

are:

1. When $x$ is large, in which case $\cosh(x)$ makes it even larger but $\log$ would bring the value back down. FP2 is more sparse for larger values. So, one should prevent $\cosh(x)$ making the value large.
2. When $x$ is small the $\cosh(x)$ is close to $1$. This is cool on its own. FP2 is densest near $1$, but then $\log$ becomes close to $0$. In this case it is better to approximate the function $\log(1+x)$ and the function $\cosh(x)-1$ and compose those.

So, for $x$ large one can approximate $\cosh(x)$ by $\frac{e^x}{2}$. Composing with $\log(x)$ one gets $x-\log(2)$.

For $x$ small we can write $\cosh(x)=1+\frac{(e^x-1)^2}{2e^x}$ and compute $\log(\cosh(x))$ by composing $\log(1+x)$ and $\frac{(e^x-1)^2}{2e^x}$. The latter would be computed by approximating $e^x-1$ directly and not by evaluating $e^x$ and subtracting $1$. A C++ implementation could compute $\log(1+x)$ using `std::log1p(x)` and $e^x-1$ using `std::expm1(x)`.

Finally, one needs to investigate what would be good value $x_1,x_2$ such that one would use

1. the last computation on the interval $[0,x_1]$,
2. the computation `std::log(std::cosh(x))` on $(x_1,x_2]$
3. and `x-std::log(2)` on the $[x_2,\infty]$.